# page adapter around image(android)

Tags: android

I want to create a swipe image layout like the following example:

I have 3 images, in display 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2-> 3 .... and it circles through the images.

This is my code that I tried creating this with, but it doesn't loop, I have 1 -> 2 -> 3 and end.

```
public class ImageAdapterDetailS extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] image;
    Context context;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public ImageAdapterDetailS(Context context, String[] mas){
        this.context=context;
        image = mas;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        Log.e("position ", String.valueOf(position));
        //this is my super algoritm
        if(position >= image.length) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(image[0], imageView);
        } else {
            imageLoader.displayImage(image[position], imageView);
        }

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify getCount()

```
public int getCount(){
    return image.length * 500;
}
```

and the way to get the correct image:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(image[position % image.length], imageView);
```

If you want it to loop call (assuming your using a ViewPager called viewPager):

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(image.length * 250);
```